# itemDoubleClicked signal is not emitted when mouseDoubleClickEvent is implemented

Tags: c++, qt

I'm implementing a class that inherits the QTreeWidget,
I'm trying to do something only when the user left-clicks on an item.
Since itemDoubleClicked only gives you the item and not the mouse event,
and mouseDoubleClickEvent only gives you the mouse event with no item,
so I thought I would add a member in the class and record whether left or right button was pressed in mouseDoubleClickEvent, 
then check that info when entering the slot connected to signal itemDoubleClicked.
That is, if the signal is emitted after the event handler. I was planning on experimenting if this was true, but then I ran into this issue.
Ok, back to the class, it looks something like this:

```
class myTreeWidget : public QTreeWidget{
    Q_OBJECT

    private:
        Qt::MouseButton m_button;

    public:
        myTreeWidget(QWidget* parent):QTreeWidget(parent){
            m_button = Qt::NoButton;
            connect(this, SIGNAL(itemDoubleClicked(QTreeWidgetItem*, int)), 
                    this, SLOT(slot_doubleClick(QTreeWidgetItem*,int)));
        }

        void mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent* event){
            m_button = event->button();
        }

    public slots:
        void slot_doubleClick(QTreeWidgetItem* item, int column);

    signals:
        void itemDoubleClicked(QTreeWidgetItem* item, int column);
}
```

Yep, something like this.
Then I used gdb to check which was called first,
mouseDoubleClickEvent or slot_doubleClick, 
and it turns out that slot_doubleClick was not called at all.
I commented out mouseDoubleClickEvent and tried again, 
and slot_doubleClick was called.

So um... what I'm asking here is...
is this a limitation in Qt? 
Can I only choose one between signals&slots and event handlers?
Or am I just doing it wrong?

Moreover, if this is a limitation, 
can you recommend another solution to what I'm trying to do?
(only respond to left double-clicks)

Sorry for the long post and thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you override some event handler and want also default behavior, you should call base handler implementation. For example try this:

```
void mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent* event){
     m_button = event->button();
       QTreeWidget::mouseDoubleClickEvent(event);
}
```